# How to remove Linux permissions on files for emailing to a Windows user

Tags: permissions, windows, email

A friend needed some help with LaTeX so I created some files, zipped it and mailed it. My friend (who is running Windows 8.1) could open but not edit the files I sent, due to write-permissions. I suggested creating a new file and manually copying the contents over. I consider that a nasty solution. Is there a more elegant way to handle files being transferred from a Linux system to a Windows system?

Here is some info on what I sent:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 john users     4096 Feb  2 14:02 latex_for_jane
-rw-r--r--  1 john users  6468908 Feb  2 15:30 latex_for_jane.zip
```

The top one is the folder containing all files. The bottom one is the zip I actually sent.

Comment: It would help if you provide the current permissions of the file you are sending.

Comment: What are the permissions of the files that are in the `latex_for_jane` folder that your friend can't edit?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 john users   1471 Feb  2 13:54 CivilLitReview.tex`

I do understand that `w` is missing for `group` and `other`. But do I have to `chmod` each time I mail something to a friend using Windows?

Comment: Unzipping an archive should result is files writeable by the user doing the unzipping. I find it unexpected that a Windows user would have trouble here. Did they actually unzip the contents into some folder somewhere, or did they use the quick view or whatever? Perhaps this is more a windows problem than unix/linux. I don't even think zip stores permissions.

Comment: @wurtel, You are right, zip does not store file permissions in the archive. cfbaptista, How are you creating the zip file? Are you creating it with tar, but calling it zip? Can you show the command you are using to create the zip archive?

Comment: Yes the zip files was unzipped. Maybe unrelated, but I removed the `.zip` extension prior to mailing because gmail was complaining about something. I had my friend edit the filename to include `.zip` prior to unzipping.

Comment: I found some extra info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip/434689#434689 but again I don't think the unix `zip` does this by default.

Comment: I did not use the command-line. I used the right-click menu in Krusader: `Compress` > `As ZIP Archive`

Answer (score 2):

The issue likely isn't permissions-related (at least not on the Linux side).  Once the recipient downloads the attachment, the file is owned by them.  So is anything they take out of that zip file.

I suspect the issue is one of the following:

1. The recipient is trying to edit the file without downloading/unzipping it.  Some file editors are smart enough to ask you to save the file somewhere else in this situation, but some will just give you errors about "Could not save file".
2. The recipient's e-mail client has placed the files in some variety of [Protected View](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653)/[Blocked](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/windows-7-security-blocks-potentially-harmful-file/4f9a3014-06bc-46e6-802c-154f3de1ea38) status.

Have the recipient download the attachment to their desktop.  Right click on the zip file, go to properties, and look at the bottom for a security warning ("This file came from another computer and might be blocked...").  If they see that, have them click "Unblock," then proceed with opening the zip file.  Copy the compressed "latex_for_jane" file to their desktop.  Open it and see if they can now edit the file.

Also, you might want to put a file extension on that original file ("latex_for_jane.txt" or "latex_for_jane.tex").  That'll save your Windows compatriot some trouble.